# Firebase storage - how to solve when multiple users are updating one file without overwriting other user's changes?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, overwrite

I'm using Firebase storage, where I store json files for example list of users with some details like this:

```
{
"1sVy3yHuxHcIihT1IJGpInKgu": {
"username": "David",
"email": "david@gmail.com",
"events": [
"1680093058892",
"1680095016534"
],
"role": "ADMIN"
},
"x9DT96y9Xrc9t3nC5R2ME9CSq": {
"username": "Sara",
"email": "sara@gmail.com",
"events": [],
"role": "USER"
}
}
```

This file can be updated with multiple actions (new user added, current user's data update,...). To update a file, I download it, then make changes and upload it back, where it overwrites the old file. But when multiple changes are being done simultaneously, one user can overwrite changes made by others. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Why won't store that data in Firestore or the in Realtime Database?

Comment: @AlexMamo From Firebase Storage I can simply download/upload my files. I'm on Spark plan for now and as far as I know, the Firestore Database import/export doesn't work on Spark. Or is there a way to download or upload all data from/to Firestore Database or Realtime Database with Spark plan?

Comment: I was referring to using the client SDK and calling the corresponding update methods.

Comment: @DavidHenzl Did you have a chance to read my answer below, and maybe even check it out?

Answer (score 0):

As Alex already commented, this sounds like a scenario that is better suited for a tool that handles structured data, such as Firestore or the Realtime Database.

When using Cloud Storage, the best I can think of is to implement your own compare-and-set mechanism using the metadata of the rules, and Firebase's server-side [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security). The steps needed:

1. Include a version number in the metadata of each file, e.g. `version: 1`.
2. When updating a file:

   1. Remember the current version number of the files.
   2. Update the data in your application code.
   3. Determine the new version number, e.g. `version: 2`
   4. Write the new data with an updated version number **and** the previous version number, e.g. `version: 2, previous_version: 1`
3. In your security rules, only allow a write when the `previous_version` of the `request.resource` (the file as it will be after updating) variable is the same as the `version` of the `resource` (the file as it was before the update).

   Something along the lines of:

   ```
   allow write: if request.resource.previous_version == resource.version
   ```

With this, the server will reject writes that are based on an outdated version, and the client can catch that error and retry it's update (so re-read the data, and try it again).

The above is pretty much what the Firebase SDKs for the Realtime Database and Firestore do when you run a transaction.